# java.sql.SQLException: datatype mismatch inserting values from CSV to table sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite, csv

I created a database `sandapp.db` using sqlite and it has a `salesman` table initially with the columns:

```
-----------
|code|name|
-----------
```

The values of these columns come from a .csv file and there were no troubles in inserting the data from .csv file to sqlite db. Here was the working code:

```
public static String importSalesmanFile(String filepath){
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO SALESMAN VALUES (?,?)";
    String status = "";
    CSVReader reader = null; 
    Connection connection = null; 
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepath), ',');
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        String[] rowData = null;

        int i = 0;
        while((rowData = reader.readNext()) != null){
            for (String data : rowData){
                pstmt.setString((i % 2) + 1, data);
                if (++i % 2 == 0)
                    pstmt.addBatch();
                if (i % 20 == 0)
                    pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        status = "Successfully uploaded";
    }   catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally { 
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SalesmanDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }           
    return status;        
}
```

Then I had to add the variable `isSelected` which has a default value of `0` that will change to `1` if the Salesman is selected to the in the program. So I revised the working code above to this. So my new sandapp.db would be

```
---------------------
|code|name|isSelected|
---------------------
```

And I updated my code BUT NetBeans would give back an error `java.sql.SQLException: datatype mismatch`

Updated code that gives back the error:

```
public static String importSalesmanFile(String filepath){
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO SALESMAN VALUES (?,?,?)";
    String status;
    CSVReader reader = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null; 
    try {            
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepath), ',');
        connection = DBConnection.getConnection();                        

        ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        String[] rowData = null;

        int i = 0;
        while((rowData = reader.readNext()) != null){
            for (String data : rowData){
                ps.setString((i % 3) + 1, data); //changed this
                if (++i % 3 == 0){//changed this
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                if (i % 30 == 0){ //changed this
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }
        }
        status = "Successfully Uploaded";
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.print(e.getMessage());
        status = "Error - Upload Salesman file again.";
    }
    return status;
}
```

I updated my `Salesman` entity class:

```
public class Salesman {
private int code;
private String name;
private int isSelected = 0;        

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getIsSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setIsSelected(int isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = 0;
}
```

}

I updated my getSalesman() method:

```
public static ArrayList<Salesman> getSalesman(){
    ArrayList<Salesman> salesList = new ArrayList<Salesman>();
    Salesman salesman;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM salesman";
    try {
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();
        while(r.next()){
            salesman = new Salesman();

            salesman.setCode(r.getInt("code"));
            salesman.setName(r.getString("name"));
            salesman.setIsSelected(r.getInt("isSelected"));

            salesList.add(salesman);
        }
        ps.close();
        connection.close();
        r.close();
        return salesList;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SalesmanDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Lastly, this is my `salesman` create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "salesman" (
`code`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`isSelected`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(code)
)
```

Console showed that this line is source of error:

```
if (i % 30 == 0){
  ps.executeBatch(); //here
}
```

Comment: are you sure your csv file is updated?? seems csv file might be corrupted

Comment: Please add related csv file entries to the question

Comment: @Boola i checked my csv file and yes, there was a bug! gash thank you thank you!!